# How to save an animation in image format using Javafx?

Tags: javafx

I had seen a sample in NetBeans for Javafx wherein fireworks are being animated over an image. I want to save that whole sample in an image format. How to do it?

Comment: Do you want just a snapshot of the image or save the whole animation?

Comment: I want to save the whole animation. Like in Gif images we have animations